Online service or application for formatting Nginx configuration files
The OS used on the PC is Linux.
How I want it:
Since the configuration files can be large. I want to have an application that helps monitor the indents between directives, missing brackets and other things. Which are easy to miss.
It may also give some recommendations on the best practices for compiling these files.
How I do it now:
At the moment, I connect to the server via ssh and edit this file via nano, which is not always convenient.
There is a more convenient option to connect to the server via sftp, through the GNOME Files graphical interface and open the .conf file locally in the Sublime Text application.
